# TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING calls twice while one call ringing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I use descendant - class of PhoneStateListener:

```
 class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
      switch (state) {
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              if (incomingNumber!=null)
              {
                // code for incoming call handling
              }


          break;           

      }
      super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
  }
```

this is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     CallStateListener phoneListener;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (phoneListener == null) {
            phoneListener = CallStateListener.getCallStateInstance(context);


            TelephonyManagerSingletone.getInstance().getTelephonyManager().listen(CallStateListener.getCallStateInstance(context),
                    android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


        }   
}
```

manifest:

```
  <receiver android:name="com.library.ServiceReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but when I use it like this, I receive duplicate call in my CallStateListener. How can I fix this?

Comment: you call listen twice because your receiver receives 2 actions

Comment: but there're two different actions - for outgoing and incoming calls. And this is occurs not always - it occurs sometimes. And how can I make my BroadcastReceiver to listen both incoming and outcoming calls?

Comment: I removed NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action, but the problems remains.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried your code, it run 10 times instead of running just once! It is better to declare `phoneListener` as a static variable in this case. That way you can guarantee that `listen` method will not be called more than once. Check this out:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static CallStateListener phoneListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (phoneListener == null) {
            phoneListener = new CallStateListener();
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService("phone");
            tm.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }

}
```

Also, I have changed the way you deal with `TelephonyManager` - I couldn't find that `TelephonyManagerSingletone` that you mentioned in your code.

I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a bug or a feature, but since API19 that happens with broadcasts.

For those who will search for the solution - you can keep track of previous state. Do stuff only if it is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**if you add these permissions then your BroadcastReceiver received twice**.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager
**ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED**

public static final String ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED
Broadcast intent action indicating that the call state on the device has changed.

The EXTRA_STATE extra indicates the new call state. If a receiving app has Manifest.permission.**READ_CALL_LOG** permission, a second extra EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER provides the phone number for incoming and outgoing calls as a String.

If the receiving app has **Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG** and **Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE** permission, **it will receive the broadcast twice;** one with the EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER populated with the phone number, and another with it blank. Due to the nature of broadcasts, you cannot assume the order in which these broadcasts will arrive, however you are guaranteed to receive two in this case. Apps which are interested in the EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER can ignore the broadcasts where EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER is not present in the extras (e.g. where Intent#hasExtra(String) returns false).
**you can use one condition and this problem solved**

```
if (!intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)){
            //Do your work or code in this section
}
```