# Call two times service

Tags: android, call

> I have this code for when anyone call me store in database but when anyone call me this caused two times saved number and date in the same time,all code for my problem phone service..

```
CallBlocker = new BroadcastReceiver() {         

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class c = null;
            try {
                c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Method m = null;
            try {
                m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephonyManager);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
```

///acording pnone state

```
     PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener() 
        {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber) 
            {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                {

                    if (blockAll_cb.isChecked() && sarjda) 
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                        phoneNo = incomingNumber;


                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss");
                        String tarih = sdf.format(new Date());
                        gelenArama.createGelenArama(new GelenAramaItem(phoneNo, tarih));


                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                triggerNotification();
                            }
                        };
                        timer.schedule(timerTask, 20000);
                    }

                }
            }
        };          

    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);
```

Comment: What's your question? We aren't psychic - just showing your code and an unclear title aren't enough to understand what help you need.

Comment: I saved call number in sql database when anyone calling me, but this code saved two times any calling.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853511/telephonymanager-call-state-ringing-calls-twice-while-one-call-ringing), it might happen if your CallStateListener isn´t declared static.

From [TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING calls twice while one call ringing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853511/telephonymanager-call-state-ringing-calls-twice-while-one-call-ringing):

```js
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static CallStateListener phoneListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (phoneListener == null) {
            phoneListener = new CallStateListener();
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService("phone");
            tm.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }

}
```